# page is localized automatically after publishing

Tags: 2013

When i publish a page the page is localized automatically.
The page has used some TBB which reads the label value from some component. I have localized the component before publishing the page.

I am not able to understand the problem. Please help

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have some Event System code that automatically localizes the Page after it has been published. Or a GUI Extension or some other custom code.

Tridion certainly doesn't localize Pages unless something tells it to do so.

Comment: I have not aware that any kind of Event system code or custom code is written for this. But i will check as you mentioned it.